# How resolve "Error: invalid reporter "html-cov"" in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "learningmocha",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
   "test": "mocha && mocha test --require blanket --reporter html-cov >   coverage.html"
   },
  "author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"blanket": "^1.2.3",
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"mocha": "^3.2.0"
},
"config": {
"blanket": {
  "pattern": [ "index.js" ],
  "data-cover-never": "node-module"
  }
 }
}
```

I am using Mocha for testing in nodejs. when i run npm test after adding html-cov in the test script of my package.json as show above then it give me error

> "Error: invalid reporter "html-cov"

You can see more in this image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`html-cov` was dropped in 3.0.0 [1]

[1] https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2356

Comment: so what is the alternative for "html-cov" to work with blanket.js?

Comment: I've not looked into it but a quick Google reveals this https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome ? Could give that a try